# overriding equals and hashCode in Collection

Tags: java, collections

I am new in `Collection`, as per my knowledge I have already override the `hashCode()` and `Equals()` method in `Data` class, but when I trying to search the element it is giving "not found". Why? Please look at the code below aand help me to find the bug.

```
import java.util.*;

public class WordCounter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashSet<Data> set=new HashSet<Data>();  
        set.add(new Data("this",2));
        set.add(new Data("that",3));
        set.add(new Data("which",6));
        set.add(new Data("how",7));

        System.out.println(new Data("how",7).hashCode());

        set.add(new Data("hey",3));
        set.add(new Data("me",5));

        Iterator<Data> itr=set.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Data d=itr.next();
            d.display();
        }
        Data e=new Data("how",7);
        System.out.println(e.hashCode()+"\t");
        if(set.contains(e))
            System.out.println("found");
        else
            System.out.println("not found");

    }
}
```

Data Class:

```
class Data {
    String word;
    int fre;

    public Data(String w,int f) {
        word=w;
        fre=f;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(word+"\t"+fre);
    }

    public boolean equals(Data e) {
        return this.word.equals(e.word) && this.fre == e.fre;   
    }

    public  int hashCode() {
        return this.word.hashCode() + this.fre;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps your equals method is not used?

The signature is

```
public boolean equals(Object obj);
```

And it appears you have

```
public boolean equals(Data e);
```

Consider adding `@Override`annotations when you want to override a parent method (in this case java.lang.Object)

**Update**

Changing your method to this solves the case.

```
public boolean equals(Object d) {
    Data e = (Data) d;
    return this.word.equals(e.word) && this.fre == e.fre;
}
```

Comment: "Perhaps"...? Those are **overloaded** methods, of course it's not using the methods provided. +1 for adding annotations, most IDEs have an option to add missing ones.

Comment: "But I have use generics it is ging error when I am using  public boolean equals(Object obj) "

Comment: Yes, there is no perhaps, sorry. I was merely trying to present him the question he should have asked himself.

Comment: equals(Data) and equals(Object) are not the same. I see no use of generics in class Data. I have tested your code locally, and I can augment it correctly.

Comment: "sorry ,I don't understand ,will u please explain again or write a correct code for me."

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen, you are not checking if `d` is in fact `Data` before casting it.

Comment: A type check is required `if (!(d instanceof Data)) return false`

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen,thanks Neils ,your help is very useful,now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You `equals()` method is not used, because it has wrong signature. The correct signature is `public boolean equals(Object o){ /* ... */ }`. Because the signatures don't match, you are effectively **overloading** the method instead of **overriding**. The working `equals()` example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object e)
{
    if(!(e instanceof Data)){
        return false;
    }
    Data d = (Data)e;
    return this.word.equals(d.word) && this.fre == d.fre;
}
```

When overriding a method, use the `@Override` annotation - then the code fails to compile if the signatures don't match, thus:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Data d){ ... }
```

Will give you an error and save some debugging time. Also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).